# Perl hash data check in IF condition not working

Tags: perl, if-statement, hash

I'm new to perl and I'm working on perl code which use hashes.
I wonder why I can't use hash data in a IF condition.
For example,

Value of `$post_val{'module'}` is `extension`.

```
print "Module value: $post_val{'module'}\n";

if (chomp($post_val{'module'}) eq "extension") {
    print "correct...\n";
} else {
    print "wrong...\n";
}
```

I get following output,

> Module value: extension
>
> wrong...

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chomp` returns the number of characters removed, in this case `1`.

```
chomp $post_val{'module'};
if ($post_val{'module'} eq "extension") {
    print "correct...\n";
} else {
    print "wrong...\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was misunderstood the chomp function.

Answer (score 3):

[`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) returns the number of characters removed, not the `chomp`ed string.

```
chomp($post_val{module})
if ($post_val{module} eq 'extension') {
  ...
```